# Google app script setValues() runs perfectly until it reaches a data validation error

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This works perfectly if none of the data-validated cells raise an error on the sheet being written to. However, once the script reaches a cell where the copied value doesn't follow the data validation rules, it returns an error and stops executing. How can I ignore this error, continue to write into the cell, and continue running the script?

```
function addNew() {
  Week = "2022-01-03"
  x = 4
  y = 17

  for (var i=0; i<21; i++) 
  {
    var readRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(`Versionality!I${x}:K${y}`)
    var readValues = readRange.getValues();
    var writeRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("------");

    var writeValues = writeRange.getRange(`${Week}!H${x}:J${y}`)
    writeValues.setValues(readValues);

    x += 17
    y += 17
  }
}
```

Comment: writeRange is undefined

Comment: Perhaps you should remove validation prior to writing new data over those ranges

Comment: Why do you have validation if you're just going to write values regardless of the results of the validation?

Comment: @cooper If I remove validation before writing, is it possible to add it back after writing and not have it raise error while writing?

Comment: @tibrogaran I need to copy-paste the range from the last version. The data validation only supports the new IDs. I would like to overwrite, then go back and see what's changed based on the validation errors.

Comment: It's always possible to add the DataValidation back.  As for not creating errors, I guess that would depend upon what you have written, not sure.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481010/google-app-script-ignore-data-validation-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can “disable/enable” data validation to copy data:

#### Sample code:

```js
function myFunction(){
  // IMPORTANT: Make sure source and target dimensions are the same.

  var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("source!B11:D11"); //Get source range of cells to be copied
  var sourceRangeDVs = sourceRange.getDataValidations(); // cache the data validations currently applied to the sourceRange
  sourceRange.clearDataValidations(); //clear validations on the source range before getting source values
  var sourceValues = rangeSource.getValues(); //getting source values

  //Next, get target range where the data will be set. 
  //Note: if you have to open a new file and you are handling several ranges to be copied in a loop, 
  //    you may want to cache the target file on a variable to avoid opening every iteration of the loop
  var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("target!E6:G6"); //Get target range of cells for the values to be set
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues); //Set values copied from source in the target range

  sourceRange.setDataValidations(sourceRangeDVs); //Set Data Validations cached back to source range
}
```

Please note that the spreadsheet names and ranges set on the sample code above are merely to exemplify, please modify it accordingly.

Comment: This worked well. I just had to swap and clear the targetRange data validations instead of the source range

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose this.  You are doing a lot of getValues()/setValues() which can cause a performance issue.  What I like to do is use only one getValues() and then we can extract what we need from the full array and write our portions of it as needed.

Also you were repeatedly opening the same spreadsheet by id.

I didn't test it because your date structure would be too hard to set up.  But I'm pretty confident it will work.

```
function addNew() {
  let Week = "2022-01-03";
  let x = 3;  // array index is 1 less than row
  let y = 17;

  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let readSheet = spread.getSheetByName("Versionality");
  let readValues = readSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let writeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("------").getSheetByName(Week);

  for (let i=0; i<21; i++)  {
    let subArray = [];
    let j=x;
    while( j < y ) {
      subArray.push(readValues[j].slice(7,10)); // columns I to K
      j++;
    }

    writeSheet.getRange(x+1,8,14,3).setValues(subArray);  // columns H to J 

    x += 17;
    y += 17;
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the savings on performance. I was able to take it from minutes of getting and setting each range to seconds. Instead of slicing from 7,10, I sliced from 8-11 because google sheets starts counting at index 1.

Comment: Sorry about the 7 vs. 8 I must have miss counted on my fingers.  I is column 9 but array index 8.